# SassError: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3. in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sass, compass-sass

i was building my web app in Reactjs when i had to download the module @compass/css3, i've downloaded this module but still giving me this error:

`SassError: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3.  >> @import "compass/css3";`

i've tried to download only the 'compass' module but nothing.

How could i fix this issue? Thanks!!

Comment: try `@import "~compass/css3";`

Comment: it show me the same error unfortunatly :(

Comment: do you have the package installed?

Comment: Yeah, the only package i've download it was 'compass' because if i try to download 'compass/css3' it gives me errors, probably was deprecated

Comment: looks like compass is a ruby package and not js

Comment: Yeah you right, i've searched now on google and it looks like that the most people use this package on ruby, anyway thank u so much!